# Problema con tabla sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy creando la tabla para el registro de mi pagina web, pero al hacerla me salieron demasiados fallos, los cuales son:

[image: introducir el código aquí]

El codigo es el siguiente:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'usuarios'(
    'idusuarios' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    'user' varchar(16) NOT NULL,
    'email' varchar(80) NOT NULL,
    'password' varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ('idusuarios')
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=11;
```

Toda respuesta, comentario o ayuda es bien recibida, muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score 3):

Como puedes leer en la [propia documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html)

- El caracter usado como identificador de cita es la *comilla simple invertida* o *backtick* **`** quedando en una sentencia SQL así:

  ```
  CREATE TABLE `algo` (
  ```
- El mismo enlace nos aclara que para poder usar por ejemplo comillas dobles como identificador, debemos habilitar a [*ANSI_QUOTES*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes)

Sin embargo con este último punto debes ser cuidadoso por que y cito<sup>1</sup>:

> Treat " as an identifier quote character (like the `quote character) and not as a string quote character. You can still use` to quote identifiers with this mode enabled. With ANSI_QUOTES enabled, you cannot use double quotation marks to quote literal strings because they are interpreted as identifiers.

Que se puede traducir como:

> Usar "como un carácter de comillas dobles de identificador (como el carácter de comillas`) y no como un carácter de comillas de cadena. Aún puede usar` para citar identificadores con este modo habilitado. Con ANSI_QUOTES habilitado, no puede usar comillas dobles para citar cadenas literales porque se interpretan como identificadores.

**Entonces debes proceder con cuidado y yo recomendaría mejor manejar el caracter de backtick para dicho fin**

**Fuente de consulta**

- <sup>1</sup>[ANSI_QUOTES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes)

Comment: Que tal, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, Ya corregi la tabla, pero el problema sigue estando

Comment: @HatoriHanso entonces por favor no marques la respuesta como aceptada ya que no esta solucionando el problema, si puedes editar y agregar mas detalles del mensaje de error entonces puedo editar e intentar ayudar

Comment: Claro, Pero pense que como utilice tu respuesta y me sirvio, ya que me mostraste la forma correcta de utilizar las comillas, tendria que marcarla como correcta, gracias por aclararlo

Answer (score 1):

Debes usar el caracter ` (backtick) en lugar de comilla simple '

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usuarios`(
        `idusuarios` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `user` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
        `email` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
        `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`idusuarios`)
    )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=11;
```

Answer (score 1):

***Yo creo los Queries sin comillas***

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usuarios(
     idusuarios int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     user varchar(16) NOT NULL,
     email varchar(80) NOT NULL,
     password varchar(50) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (idusuarios) )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=11;
```