# Crear db con php

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo que crear una tabla con varios registros pero me pone un error de sintaxis en la línea  donde creo la tabla, no sé por qué. He mirado de arriba a abajo la sintaxis y me he vuelto loco con una cosa tan sencilla pero no encuentro el fallo.

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Documento sin título</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php
        require_once( 'conexion2.php' );
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE Instalaciones(
        'id' INT (10) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY_KEY,
        'nombre' VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
        'numeroPiscinas' INT(25) NOTNULL,
        'Olimpicas' DOUBLE(1) NOTNULL
        
        )";
        $result = $conn->query( $sql );
    if ( ! $result ) {
        die ( 'Could not run query: ' . $conn->error );
    }

    $rows = $result->fetch_all( MYSQLI_ASSOC );
        function hsc( $s ) {
        return htmlspecialchars( $s, ENT_QUOTES );
    }
        
        ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Este es *principal2.php* y ahora os enseño la *conexion2.php*

```php
<?php $user   = "Alex";
    $pass   = "CCAlex_vs15";
    $server = "localhost:3307";
    $db     = "clubdenatacion";

    $conn = new mysqli( $server, $user, $pass, $db );
    if ( $conn->connect_errno ) {
        die ( "Couldn't connect to database: " . $conn->connect_error );
    }
```

Comment: Muestra el error que te esta saliendo para tener mayores antecedentes

Comment: No se pudo ejecutar la consulta: tiene un error en su sintaxis SQL; consulte el manual que corresponde a la versión de su servidor MySQL para conocer la sintaxis correcta para usar cerca de ''id' INT (10) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY_KEY, 'nombre' VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 'n' en la línea 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto es un problema de SQL, la sintaxis está mal y muy mal. Ver la documentación de [crear una tabla](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-table/).

Ver [cómo crear una llave primaria](https://mariadb.com/docs/sql/features/constraints/xpand/primary-key/)

Los nombres de las columnas no llevan comillas simples. A lo mucho pueden llevar [tildes invertidas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/384699/80870) (backtick).

Hay inconsistencia en el [uso de DOUBLE](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/164139/80870), si no lo necesitas, usa FLOAT u otro tipo de datos adecuado

La consulta sin esos errores queda:

```
CREATE TABLE Instalaciones(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nombre VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    numeroPiscinas INT(25) NOT NULL,
    Olimpicas DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Esto crea la tabla sin problemas, luego más abajo tendrás otro error en `$result->fetch_all`. Esto es porque creando una tabla, no haciendo un `SELECT`, a lo mucho esto solo devuelve True o False. Y de todas formas la tabla está recién creada, o sea, está vacía. Al tratar de recorrerla va a dar error.

Comment: toda la razon hahahahah has anticipado hasta el error de después